# Table header fixing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made table which have some multiple feature like:

1. sortable
2. check and uncheck all
3. resizable column
4. table header which is fixed on the top
5. for scrollbar I am using mCustomScrollbar

Now what I want when I am using mCustomScrollbar it’s working nice but the problem is that. My table header is fixed when I am scrolling vertically its fine. But when I scroll horizontally the table header not sliding according to that. Please help me out of this I want fix the table header when I scroll vertically and when I scroll horizontally it should slide.

here is the example made by me:
https://cloud.csdcsystems.com/ui-prototype/html/approved-html/table/table-sorting.html

Comment: hi I have shown the code above link.

Comment: all the rows are in `thead` tag.. any specific reason for that .

Comment: yes I want to fix the table header.  Please help me out of this I want fix the table header when I scroll vertically and when I scroll horizontally it should slide.

Comment: Could you please make a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) so we can test and modify your code.

Comment: I can't  make in jsfiddle because there are so many scripts used.